# Rails Routing Design Question for Scoped Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

What would be the preferred routing and namespace controller scheme for a scoped resource in Rails. ie. for index of projects that are scheduled:

1) /scheduled/projects

2) /projects/scheduled

3) /projects?scheduled=true

Option 1 is kind of what our existing codebase does, every new feature that access the resource differently get its own namespace. But it seems like option 2 is a possibility as well.

Looking for opinion from folks working on sufficiently large Rails codebase with a large number of controllers.

**Option 1: scope is the namespace**

scheduled/projects=> scheduled/projects#index

```
  namespace :scheduled do
    resources :projects
  end

  resources :projects

/projects/3
bin/rails g controller projects
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
    def show
      render plain: "show projects/#{params[:id]}"
    end
end

/scheduled/projects
bin/rails g controller scheduled/projects
class Scheduled::ProjectsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      render plain: 'index scheduled/projects'
   end 
end
```

*Pros:*
All the scheduled items are group under one folder,  kind of similar to the the admin route scoping example in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/routing.html.

*Cons:*
The various scoped ProjectsController are scattered in different places.

**Option 2 - scope specified after the resource**

projects/scheduled => projects/scheduled#index

```
   namespace :projects do
    resources :scheduled
  end

   # config/routes.rb
   resources :projects


/projects/3
bin/rails g controller projects
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
    def show
      render plain: "show projects/#{params[:id]}"
    end
end

/projects/scheduled
bin/rails g controller projects/scheduled
class Projects::ScheduledController < ApplicationController
    def index
       render plain: 'index projects/scheduled'
    end 
end
```

Namespace scheme is similar to the Inboxes::PendingController example in.http://jeromedalbert.com/how-dhh-organizes-his-rails-controllers/

Inboxes is the resource like projects
Pending is the state like scheduled

*Pros:* Everything Projects related would be under the same namespace, could make it easier to share things like filtering logic

*Cons:* projects/scheduled index route could look similar to projects/:id show route with scheduled as the :id

**Option 3 - scope is the query params**

/projects?scheduled=true => projects/scheduled#index

Using advance constraint to map query params to routes.

*Pros:* all the projects related routes are simply /projects

*Cons:* maybe not all filters are applicable to a certain scoped resource. ie. /projects?scheduled=true&filter[status]=false may not make sense.